# MySql make fields accessible depending on the value of another field?

Tags: mysql

Let's assume I have the following a table in MySql with the following columns:

- state (Boolean) that can take a state of 0 or 1;
- col1 (accessible if state = 1 // meaning that it can be edited by user if state = 1)
- col2 (accessible if state = 0)
- col3 (accessible all the time)

How can make such a table in MySql?

Comment: This doesn't make sense IMO, "accessible" should be done in the "code layer". So create the table with the current columns and do the logic in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As HamZa mentioned, "accessible" should be done in code layer. Actually I agree, but it might be arguable.

An option could be to use different views. You'd create views such as

```
CREATE VIEW foo_1 AS 
SELECT state, col1, col3
FROM foo
WHERE state = 1;
```

and

```
CREATE VIEW foo_2 AS
SELECT state, col2, col3
FROM foo
WHERE state = 0;
```

But note, that there are certain restrictions for views, so they are updatable/ insertable.

The only possible problem I see so far is

> The view must contain all columns in the base table that do not have a default value.

Please have a look in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/view-updatability.html) for additional information.